# JavaFX: TextField ... Limit character input to double (no multiple commas)

Tags: javafx, textfield

In the TextField, the user is only allowed to enter a double number, e.g. "12345,12" or "123456" 
The problem is that the comma character can unfortunately be entered several times, e.g. "12345,12,,,34"

How can you limit the number of commas to a maximum of 1x?

I have come so far:

```
public class MyTextFieldOnlyDoubleWithComma extends TextField {

  public boolean ifCondition_validate(String text) {
      boolean retValue = false;
      retValue = ( text.matches("[0-9,]*" ) );
      return retValue;
  }

  @Override
  public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
      if ( ifCondition_validate(text) ) {
          super.replaceText(start, end, text);
      }     
  } 

  @Override
  public void replaceSelection(String text) {
       if ( ifCondition_validate(text) ) {
          super.replaceSelection(text);
      }
  }
}
```

Intermediate:
Many thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this is not the case. Because you can not enter ",":

```
public boolean ifCondition_validate(String text) {
    boolean retValue = false;       

    //Necessary to delete characters in Edit mode
    if(text.equals("")) { return true; }

    String text_doubleWithPoint = text.replace(",", "."); //x,yz => x.yz
    try {           
        Double.parseDouble(text_doubleWithPoint);
        retValue=true;
        System.out.println(">Input: '" + text + "' ... ok<");
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(">Input: '" + text + "' ... not allowed<");
    }

   return retValue;
}
```

Comment: You should put just numbers in matches function and manage the "," apart. Maybe with a boolean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `TextFormatter` with a filter that blocks inputs resulting in invalid text:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*|\\d+\\,\\d*");
TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter((UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>) change -> {
    return pattern.matcher(change.getControlNewText()).matches() ? change : null;
});

textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```